# How to get the default redirected printer

Tags: printing, vb6, terminal-services

I do remote connection in a terminal server. Include printer as my local resources. Then at Device Settings, I set the default as the redirected printer.

```
Dim pr As Printer
MsgBox Printer.DeviceName
'- return the default printer which I believe pulled from registry entry
'  "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device"

For Each pr In Printers
    MsgBox pr.DeviceName
Next pr
'- return the list of all available printer including from other users       ' session
```

What I am trying to achieve here is that to return the correct default printer which is the redirected one. Not this Printer.DeviceName

I believe from this registry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device\SessionDefaultDevices\{SessionID}`

Is there an existing function to pull the data here?